# display search box for each column of data grid view

Tags: c#, gridview

I want to create search ability based on text box for each column of grid view in c# `winforms` application. How do I enable this after displaying primary data grid view result in order to filter columns based on text for each one.

```
SqlConnection con = new Sql Connection(@"");
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter();
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
try
{
    cmd = new SqlCommand("sp_text_box", con);
    con.Open();
    cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@ex", combo_Box1.Text));
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    da.SelectCommand = cmd;
    da.Fill(dt);
    dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
}
catch (Exception x)
{
    MessageBox.Show(x.GetBaseException().ToString(), "Error",
           MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
}
finally
{
    cmd.Dispose();
    con.Close();
}
```

Comment: What are you doing so far? How do you fill your dgv? provide some code

Comment: i wrote a stored procedure in sql server then loaded it on form and fill my data grid view.

Comment: Filled with EF or ADO? Can you use linq? do you want to filter out rows or just make some as selected when matches with search criteria?

Comment: I am in ADO. i want to filter out rows based on text box for each column. after loading data grid view data then display text box for each column as well.

Comment: Did you check my answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First make your `dt` variable public by declaring it in a public scope, then try to fill it:

```
 cmd = new Sql_Command("sp_text_box", con);
 con.Open();
 cmd_Parameters.Add(new Sql_Parameter("@ex", combo_Box1.Text));
 cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
 da.SelectCommand = cmd;
 da.Fill(dt);
```

Then filter the data

```
dt.Select("Size >= 230 AND Sex = 'm'")
```

Pass it to dgv

```
dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
```